# Phonegap Build with Android target 28

Tags: phonegap-build

I am developing a simple app that sends a POST message to a server. I'm using phonegap build online service.

When I set Android target 28:

```xml
<preference name="android-targetSdkVersion" value="28" />
```

the app works fine in a tablet with Android 7, but does not work in my phone with Android 9 (it behaves as it does not have internet permission, POST message stays pending in the debugger)..

If I set lower targets (I tried all from 24-27) the app **works fine** in both devices.

I have

```xml
<access origin="*" />
```

so this is not the issue.

Debugger console does not complain about anything. Also I don't see anything strange in the build log, apart from the ugly message:

*WARNING: Overriding compileSdkVersion from android-25 (default) to android-28
WARNING: This is unsupported, please consider updating your phonegap version instead*

Any ideas? I'd like to stick with the online builder if possible.

thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it is simply not supported by PhoneGap Build at this time.

The latest version of the PhoneGap CLI that you can build with is 8.1.1, which uses Cordova Android version 7.1.2. [Android SDK 28 support was added in Cordova Android 8.0.0](https://cordova.apache.org/announcements/2019/02/16/cordova-android-release-8.0.0.html) and is [currently not supported by PhoneGap Build](https://build.phonegap.com/current-support).

---

[PhoneGap Build added support for Cordova Android 8.0.0 with PhoneGap CLI 9.0.0](https://blog.phonegap.com/cli-9-0-0-support-has-been-added-to-phonegap-build-da92fff6d588), which you can use by adding `<preference name="phonegap-version" value="cli-9.0.0" />` to your `config.xml`.

Comment: that must be it :(    Thanks :)